# MVC Quicktime/mov doesn't play

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, quicktime

I am trying to embed a mov onto a cshtml page, all the resources seem to be referencing properly but the video won't play.

The videos are located in the /Content/Videos directory.

I thought it was a permission issue but I granted everyone permission with no luck.

Could this be an IIS issue? (Checked mime types for mov)
or 
do I have put to do something in the global.asax (routes.IgnoreRoute) for mov files extensions?

Firebug shows when the player is clicked to play the video it does a successful get of the video but I don't think it is supposed to do a get action, I tested the same video from a plain html page opened from the file system, it doesn't invoke a get action when player is clicked.

I also tried to play the movie by typing the whole path in the address bar again no luck it just comes up with a quicktime logo with a question mark inside it.

**Script references:**

```
<script src="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/ac_quicktime.js" language="JavaScript"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/qtp_library.js" language="JavaScript"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Script to embed the video:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
        QT_WritePoster_XHTML('Click to Play', '../Content/Videos/myMovie.jpg',
        '../Content/Videos/myMovie.mov',
        '520', '296', '',
        'controller', 'true',
        'autoplay', 'true',
        'bgcolor', 'black',
        'scale', 'aspect');
//-->
</script>
<noscript>
        <object width="520" height="296" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
            codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
            <param name="src" value="../Content/Videos/myMovie.jpg" />
            <param name="href" value="../Content/Videos/myMovie.mov" />
            <param name="target" value="myself" />
            <param name="controller" value="false" />
            <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
            <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
            <embed width="720" height="496" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
                src="../Content/Videos/myMovie.jpg" href="../Content/Videos/myMovie.mov" target="myself"
                controller="false" autoplay="false" scale="aspect">
    </embed>
        </object>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research it seems that IIS does not allow the streaming of .mov files by default, it managed to get it working by installing the II7 media pack.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=93d59f79-9555-473d-a07a-e21020d1fc25&displaylang=en